# Flask API works on local device but not on heroku (Sending large strings to flask api)

Tags: python, opencv, heroku, base64

I am relatively new to creating flask apps though I am well experienced in using python. I have created a flask api which takes in an image in base64 encoding and a unique id (Related to something else), then uses a tensorflow lite model to detect what food items are in it and adds it to database. Now, this works completely fine on my local device but when I deploy it on heroku, it gives 400 Application error. I am pretty sure its to do with how I have configured it. I am hoping someone can help me point out the problem.Resoures:-

GIthub :- https://github.com/DarthSid12/Frappe-Api 
Heroku url :- https://frappe-ap.herokuapp.com 
When I did heroku logs --tail, I get this

```
[2021-08-09 07:35:22 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-08-09T07:35:23.293287+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620321+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-09 07:35:23 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620361+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620363+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620376+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620377+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620377+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620377+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620377+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620378+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620378+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620378+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620379+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620379+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620379+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620379+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620380+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620380+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620381+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620381+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620381+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620382+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620382+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620382+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620382+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620382+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 7, in <module>
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620383+00:00 app[web.1]: import cv2
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620384+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620384+00:00 app[web.1]: from .cv2 import *
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620384+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-08-09T07:35:23.620384+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-09 07:35:23 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623470+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-09 07:35:23 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623471+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623472+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623472+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623473+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623473+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623473+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623473+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623474+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623474+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623474+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623474+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623475+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623475+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623475+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623476+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623476+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623476+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623477+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623477+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623477+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623478+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623478+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623478+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623479+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 7, in <module>
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623479+00:00 app[web.1]: import cv2
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623479+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623480+00:00 app[web.1]: from .cv2 import *
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623480+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-08-09T07:35:23.623722+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-09 07:35:23 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-08-09T07:35:23.667804+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-08-09T07:35:23.667806+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
2021-08-09T07:35:23.668089+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.668091+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
2021-08-09T07:35:23.668344+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2021-08-09T07:35:23.668349+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2021-08-09T07:35:23.668508+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.668511+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2021-08-09T07:35:23.668747+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2021-08-09T07:35:23.668830+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2021-08-09T07:35:23.668831+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-08-09T07:35:23.668832+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-08-09T07:35:23.668832+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-08-09T07:35:23.668836+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-08-09T07:35:23.668856+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2021-08-09T07:35:23.668992+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2021-08-09T07:35:23.668993+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
2021-08-09T07:35:23.669135+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.669136+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
2021-08-09T07:35:23.669304+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.669305+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2021-08-09T07:35:23.669449+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.669450+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2021-08-09T07:35:23.669615+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2021-08-09T07:35:23.669616+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2021-08-09T07:35:23.669817+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.669844+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2021-08-09T07:35:23.670032+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2021-08-09T07:35:23.670032+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2021-08-09T07:35:23.670200+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2021-08-09T07:35:23.670201+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2021-08-09T07:35:23.670431+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2021-08-09T07:35:23.670472+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2021-08-09T07:35:23.762460+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-08-09T07:35:23.922071+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-08-09T07:35:26.268296+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=frappe-ap.herokuapp.com request_id=1c065508-2c1b-4b91-9593-992a16af6575 fwd="122.181.67.23" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-09T07:35:26.859346+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=frappe-ap.herokuapp.com request_id=85852f34-10c6-40c2-8d1d-fd0047a80746 fwd="122.181.67.23" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-09T07:35:36.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-08-09T07:36:31.931586+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=frappe-ap.herokuapp.com request_id=8e8286c9-8ee8-4c3b-b1d2-915612959255 fwd="122.181.67.23" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-09T07:36:32.951464+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=frappe-ap.herokuapp.com request_id=4c7b52f1-40fc-4818-b570-9d4a469a26fb fwd="122.181.67.23" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-09T07:39:32.054690+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=frappe-ap.herokuapp.com request_id=e2c9cf46-fa5f-4062-ba45-af899a925c9b fwd="122.181.67.23" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-09T07:39:33.058616+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=frappe-ap.herokuapp.com request_id=4118a056-a9e5-4751-981c-69cd1001096b fwd="122.181.67.23" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

So thanks to the comments, I managed to fix this. Though I keep recieving 400 request error. I have narrowed it down to this. I need to transfer an image, so for that I am using a base64 string. But this is really long and because of including that in headers, I get an error. So the question boils down to, how do u send super large strings to an api OR how to send an image to api which is clicked locally
This only happens on heroku, not on my local device

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you reviewed the error messages in that log? The error has nothing to do with Flask. It says `ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. It looks like the runtime environment is missing a shared library required by the opencv package.

Comment: I thought so. But when I download the  github in a new virtual env, install the requirements.txt, and run it, it works fine. Could you please check and maybe help me add the req. libraries? I am going to try but would love it if u could help

Comment: The dependency is for a system library, which is not covered (directly) by your `requirements.txt` file (which only handles *python* dependencies). I don't know enough about Heroku's runtime to provide the appropriate guidance here; hopefully someone else will have more information for y ou.

Comment: I did it, and a lot of other stuff, now I am stuck with one final problem I believe, please check the updated question